# How to implement mapping via automapper in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, automapper

I have two class. *PRODUCT* comes from Entity Framework, and *Product* in Domain solution: Here are the details: 
PRODUCT class (source):

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class PRODUCT
{
    public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public decimal PRODUCT_PRICE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CATEGORY { get; set; }
}
}
```

Product class (destination):

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ProductDescription {get;set;}
    public decimal ProductPrice {get;set;}
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

}

Here is the ProductViewModel that used throughout the project:

```
   public class ProductsListViewModel
{

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public PagingInfo _pagingInfo { get; set; }

    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }

    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my mapping in the project, I have a automapper to map these two.

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>();


        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductCategory,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PRODUCT_CATEGORY));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductDescription,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PRODUCT_ID));


        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PRODUCT_NAME));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PRODUCT, Product>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductPrice,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PRODUCT_PRICE));


    }
}
```

I call RegisterMappings in the Global.asax.cs's *Application_Start*.

```
   protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
    }
```

Under these circumstances, I read the contents from Entity framework, their type is PRODUCT, when I try to assign it to Product, I got error. The point that I get error is here:

```
    public ActionResult List(string category,int page = 1)
    {
        List<PRODUCT> pr = null;

        using(ProductContext pb = new ProductContext())
        {

            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                //Error is here
                Products = pb.ProductsList.Where(p => category == null || p.PRODUCT_CATEGORY == category).OrderBy(i => i.PRODUCT_ID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).ToList().Take(PageSize).ToList(),
                _pagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = category == null ? pb.ProductsList.Count() : pb.ProductsList.Where(e => e.PRODUCT_CATEGORY == category).Count()
                },
                CurrentCategory = category
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The error is this:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the ProductsList object? Also, why not setup mappings for Product -> ProductsListViewModel?

Comment: It is:         public virtual DbSet<PRODUCT> ProductsList { get; set; }  It holds the objects  come from the database.

Comment: *ProductsListViewModel* class has a property :                                         public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }   Namely, *ProductsListViewModel*  contains a list of the *Product* class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says everything you need to know. In somewhere you are trying to put a List of objects to a IEnumerable of the same objects.

It seems to me that you shoud alter the line

```
Products = pb.ProductsList.Where(p => category == null || p.PRODUCT_CATEGORY == category)
.OrderBy(i => i.PRODUCT_ID)
.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
.ToList().Take(PageSize).ToList()
```

into

```
Products = pb.ProductsList.Where(p => category == null || p.PRODUCT_CATEGORY == category)
.OrderBy(i => i.PRODUCT_ID)
.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
.Take(PageSize).AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: I am getting the error -->   Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.PRODUCT>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\benim_yazilimlarim\mvc\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Controllers\ProductController.cs 36 32 SportsStore.WebUI

Comment: It's good, the first problem has been solved and the second one comes up. In your code you should use AutoMapper functionality to convert  "SportsStore.Domain.PRODUCT" into "SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product"

Comment: I suppose I have already solved that problem in Global.asax.cs's Application_Start(). I assume that mapping has implemented throughout the project. Shall I declare it in every Controller action?

Comment: Declaring mapping is the first part, the second part is calling "Map" method everywhere you want to mapping takes place in your code and of course it would be in your action method in the controller.